# Html helper syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an MVC project without Razor.  Therefore Html helpers are wrapped in <% and %>.

My question is what are the differences between <%= and <%: ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<%= creates html markup - renders html elements in page
<%: encodes as display text on page

So, if you put a anchor inside <%:this%> you'll see the raw markup in your page rather than a link. And by the way, in Razor, why not use @ instead of <%=

e.g. the following code produces the page below

```
<div>
    <%= "<a href='#'>test</a>" %>
    <%: "<a href='#'>test</a>" %>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, Razor is a better option but not for the project I'm currently working on.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Yeah, developers don't have freedom all the time! Coming to html, you should use <%: you text %> more often for safety, specially if the data is coming from user of external source. It reduces the risk of putting unwanted html/script in your page.